# How to test a class that makes HTTP request and parse the response data in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, mocking

I Have a Class that needs to make an HTTP request to a server in order to get some information. For example:

```
- (NSUInteger)newsCount {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSURLRequest *request = ISKBuildRequestWithURL(ISKDesktopURL, ISKGet, cookie, nil, nil);
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if (!data) {
        NSLog(@"The user's(%@) news count could not be obtained:%@", username, [error description]);
        return 0;
    }
    NSString *regExp = @"Usted tiene ([0-9]*) noticias? no leídas?";
    NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSArray *match = [stringData captureComponentsMatchedByRegex:regExp];
    [stringData release];
    if ([match count] < 2)
        return 0;
    return [[match objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
}
```

The things is that I'm unit testing (using OCUnit) the hole framework but the problem is that I need to simulate/fake what the NSURLConnection is responding in order to test different scenarios and because I can't relay on the server to test my framework.

So the question is **Which is the best ways to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always tricky to test methods that call class methods like `NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest`

Here are a couple of options:

a) Use [Matt Gallagher's invokeSupersequent macro](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/supersequent-implementation.html) to intercept the call. Your unit test would contain code like this:

```
@implementation NSURLConneciton (UnitTests)

+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error {
    if (someFlagYourTestUsesToInterceptTheCall) {        
        // return test NSData instance      
    }   
    return invokeSupersequent(request, &response, &error);
}

@end
```

Then you set `someFlagYourTestUsesToInterceptTheCall` to force it to intercept the call and return your test data.

b) Another alternative is to move that call into its own method in your class under test:

```
-(NSData *)retrieveNewsCount:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    return [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
}
```

Then intercept that call in your test case using OCMock:

```
-(void)testNewsCount {
    // instantiate your class
    id myObject = ...;
    id mock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:myObject];
    [[[mock stub] andCall:@selector(mockNewsCount:) onObject:self] retrieveNewsCount:[OCMArg any]];
    NSUInteger count = [myObject newsCount];
    // validate response
    ...
}

// in the same test class:
-(NSData *)mockNewsCount:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    // return your mock data
    return mockData;
}
```

In this case, OCMock's `stub:andCall:onObject:someMethod` intercepts just this call to your object's method in order to inject some test data at test time.